# Present simple for an action belonging to the past

Tags: present-tense

i had to try three different times. I don't know why it wont accept your address normally but it FINALLY worked

I would say I don't know why it did not accept or has not accepted . I don't understand the use of present because it finally worked. The system has accepted the address .The affirmation is not true anymore.
I suppose the choice of the present was made because of" normally"  but this affirmation is not true too, it belongs to the past

Comment: You should know by now that **you must tell us the source of a passage you are asking about**. This looks like a rather badly-expressed comment that someone has posted online.

Answer (score 0):

They're both fine.

While the past is more normal there, we often use a present in a subordinate clause if the situation we are talking about continues to the present.

Here, if the speaker says "I don't know why it wouldn't accept", they are thinking of that moment in the past when it didn't; if they say "I don't know why it won't accept" they are assuming that this is a permanent behaviour, and it would never accept it.

Comment: The problem is that it has been accepted so the situation does not  continue to the present

Comment: Which is why I said it was badly  expressed.

Comment: The fact that it did accept it eventually doesn't mean that the problem has necessarily gone away. Maybe next time it will also take three attempts.